# passing variables to another KSH script

Tags: unix, ksh

lets say I have one KSH script that creates a variable....in that KSH script I call another KSH script file and want to pass a variable from the current script to the one that it calls...how do I do that?

Comment: too vague. What is your use-case? What have you tried? What's not working?  Good luck.

Comment: you want output of one script to be the input for other ..??

Comment: yes...lets say in one script I set a variable to "my value"..(var1="my value") in the main script...then the main script calls another script and I wnat to use var1 variable in the script it just called...

Comment: `echo ${var1}` will work in the second file when set in the parent script, what is your problem? Can you show your main and your second script?

Comment: there was no problem...just needed to understand how one can do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See following example:

```
[STEP 101] # cat foo.ksh
#!/usr/bin/ksh

var='hello' ./bar.ksh
echo "[foo.ksh] var=$var"

export var='world'
./bar.ksh
echo "[foo.ksh] var=$var"
[STEP 102] # cat bar.ksh
#!/usr/bin/ksh

echo "[bar.ksh] var=$var"
[STEP 103] # ./foo.ksh
[bar.ksh] var=hello
[foo.ksh] var=
[bar.ksh] var=world
[foo.ksh] var=world
[STEP 104] #
```